# Show All in Kendo Grid page sizes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there any way to have Show All in Page Sizes array of Kendo Grid?

Here is my code

```
$("#mygrid").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
            pageSizes: [15,20,25,50,100,Show All]
     },
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this

Create customize toolbar with `DropDown`.On DropDown Change write your Code.

**View**

```
<div id="grid">
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 1,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: { validation: { required: true},editable: false, },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "Text", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

            var grid=   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                            dataSource: dataSource,
                            toolbar: [
                                {
                                    template: $("#template").html()
                                }],
                                navigatable: true,
                                pageable: {
                                pageSizes: [15,20,25,50,100]
                                },height:500,
                                columns: [
                                    "ProductName",
                                    {field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", width: 110 },
                                    { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
                                    { field: "Discontinued", width: 110 }],
                        });

                $("#grid").find(".k-grid-toolbar").insertAfter($("#grid .k-grid-content"));

                $('#category').change(function(){
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if(value != null)
                    {
                        if(value == "4")
                        {
                        grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize(grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize(parseInt(value));
                        }
                    }

                });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <label class="category-label" for="category">Show products by category:</label>
        <select id="category" style="width: 80px">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="4">Show All</option>
</select>
    </div>
</script>
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/mgdnE/163/

If you have any concern let me know.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking for this only :)

Comment: Kendo has built in support for [pagesize 'all'](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-pageable.pageSizes).

Comment: Why is this example not like on the front page of kendo ui data grid section.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why all answers looks so complicated.
The answer was very easy, here is a part of the code I'm using on real project:

```
 pageable: {
            pageSize: 10,
            pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"],
            messages: {
                itemsPerPage: "vendors",
                display: "{0}-{1} from {2} vendors",
                empty: "No data",
                allPages: "Show All"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

in Asp.Net MVC (Razor or server side) you can use `Pageable` method `PageSizes`
 in default values for ture overload set page size to : **5 10 20**

if you need custom values use IEnumerable `string collection` overload:

```
.Pageable(pageable => pageable.PageSizes(new string[] { "5", "10", "15", "20", "All" })
```

Comment: explicitly creating array as string was what worked for me.